# Reading and extracting different data from a text file and creating different objects

Tags: java

I have three text files. The first one looks like this:

> 1574683 Abyssinia 105 60 25 21 11

The second one looks like this:

> 2454438 Oceanway 112 52 20 5 8

But a small part of the third one looks like this(the rest of it goes just like that, nothing different):

> 9146578 Atilgan 98 59 18 15 20
>   1000085320 N N 
>   1000255961 N N 
>   1000511923 N N 
>   1000853206 N N
>   1001279810 N N 
>   1001791735 N N 
>   ...

I'm trying to create objects from these files and store them in an arraylist, the first two files are successful. But the last one is a bit different because each line is an object but the first line is another object that has to contain rest of the objects, with an arraylist as well. 
Here's my code:

```
String[] name_and_path_of_files = {
    "C:\\Users\\Asus\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\NesneProjesi\\src\\1574683.txt",
    "C:\\Users\\Asus\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\NesneProjesi\\src\\\\2454438.txt",
    "C:\\Users\\Asus\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\NesneProjesi\\src\\\\9146578.txt"
};
    Scanner inputFileReader = null;
    Liman liman = new Liman();
try {
    for (String fileInfo : name_and_path_of_files) {

        inputFileReader = new Scanner(new File(fileInfo));

        int line_index = 0;

        while (inputFileReader.hasNext()) {
                //String separated_numbers[] = inputFileReader.nextLine().split(" ");
                //inputFileReader.useDelimiter("\\\\d+");
                int IMO = inputFileReader.nextInt();
                String isim = inputFileReader.next();
                int Max_Konteyner_sayisi = inputFileReader.nextInt();
                int Buyuk_Konteyner_sayisi = inputFileReader.nextInt();
                int Sogutuculu_Konteyner_sayisi = inputFileReader.nextInt();
                int Toksik_Taşıma_siniri = inputFileReader.nextInt();
                int Patlayıcı_Taşıma_siniri = inputFileReader.nextInt();

                Gemi yeniGemi = new Gemi(IMO, isim, Max_Konteyner_sayisi, Buyuk_Konteyner_sayisi, Sogutuculu_Konteyner_sayisi,Toksik_Taşıma_siniri, Patlayıcı_Taşıma_siniri);
                liman.gemiEkle(yeniGemi); //gemiEkle adds ships into limans arraylist 'Gemiler'.
                System.out.println(liman.Gemiler);
                if(line_index > 0){
                int Seri_Numarasi = inputFileReader.nextInt();
                String Konteyner_Ozelligi = inputFileReader.next();
                String Icerik_Ozelligi = inputFileReader.next();
                Konteyner yeniKonteyner = new Konteyner(Seri_Numarasi,Konteyner_Ozelligi,Icerik_Ozelligi);
                yeniGemi.konteynerEkle(yeniKonteyner);
                System.out.println(yeniGemi.Konteynerler.toString());
                }
            line_index++;
        }    
    }
    //System.out.println(liman.Gemiler);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
        inputFileReader.close();
}
```

Pretty much everything works but the third file, it gets the first line successfully but when it gets to the other objects it gives an InputMismatchException on this line:

> int Max_Konteyner_sayisi = inputFileReader.nextInt();

Here's the output:

`[IMO: 1574683, İsim: Abyssinia, 105, 60, 25, 11]] 
[IMO: 1574683, İsim: Abyssinia, 105, 60, 25, 11], IMO: 2454438, İsim: Oceanway, 112, 52, 20, 8]] 
[IMO: 1574683, İsim: Abyssinia, 105, 60, 25, 11], IMO: 2454438, İsim: Oceanway, 112, 52, 20, 8], IMO: 9146578, İsim: Atilgan, 98, 59, 18, 20]]`

Comment: In code you should use only english language, also you need to read something about java code convention and not start variable names from uppercase.

Comment: I know but this is an assignment and as long as it works, I have to do it the way I'm told. I'm sorry about the language, I don't have time to translate and I think you can help my problem without knowing what the variables mean.

Comment: @Elif Şahin Concerning your recently deleted post.  `if(limanGemi.get(i).getIMO()==imo)` will not work because it is comparing reference values.  You want to do something like this: `if(limanGemi.get(i).getIMO().equals(imo))` to compare the IMO numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only use hasNextInt(): from what i could make out of your design so far, you need the following changes:

```
    String[] name_and_path_of_files = {
        "C:\\Users\\Asus\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\NesneProjesi\\src\\1574683.txt",
        "C:\\Users\\Asus\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\NesneProjesi\\src\\\\2454438.txt",
        "C:\\Users\\Asus\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\NesneProjesi\\src\\\\9146578.txt"
    };
        Scanner inputFileReader = null;
        Liman liman = new Liman();
    try {
        for (String fileInfo : name_and_path_of_files) {

            inputFileReader = new Scanner(new File(fileInfo));

            int line_index = 0;
            Gemi yeniGemi = null; //---declare your arraylist-containing object here.
            while (inputFileReader.hasNext()) {
                    //String separated_numbers[] = inputFileReader.nextLine().split(" ");
                    //inputFileReader.useDelimiter("\\\\d+");
                    int IMO = inputFileReader.nextInt();
                    String isim = inputFileReader.next();
                    if(inputFileReader.hasNextInt()){
                        int Max_Konteyner_sayisi = inputFileReader.nextInt();
                        int Buyuk_Konteyner_sayisi = inputFileReader.nextInt();
                        int Sogutuculu_Konteyner_sayisi = inputFileReader.nextInt();
                        int Toksik_Taşıma_siniri = inputFileReader.nextInt();
                        int Patlayıcı_Taşıma_siniri = inputFileReader.nextInt();
                        yeniGemi = new Gemi(IMO, isim, Max_Konteyner_sayisi, Buyuk_Konteyner_sayisi,
                                Sogutuculu_Konteyner_sayisi,Toksik_Taşıma_siniri, Patlayıcı_Taşıma_siniri)
                        liman.gemiEkle(yeniGemi); //gemiEkle adds ships into limans arraylist 'Gemiler'.
                        System.out.println(liman.Gemiler);
                    }
                    else{
                        //int Seri_Numarasi = inputFileReader.nextInt();//---why repeat when you have retrived this line's leading values?
                        //String Konteyner_Ozelligi = inputFileReader.next();
                        String Icerik_Ozelligi = inputFileReader.next();
                        Konteyner yeniKonteyner = new Konteyner(IMO,isim,Icerik_Ozelligi);
                        yeniGemi.konteynerEkle(yeniKonteyner);
                        System.out.println(yeniGemi.Konteynerler.toString());
                        }
            }    
        }
        //System.out.println(liman.Gemiler);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
            inputFileReader.close();
    }
```

Comment: Help me out here, because I'm having trouble with this. If I do it this way, if and else become separate things and so the third type of object can't see the arraylist in the other object. I have to store the third type of object in the arraylist which the other type of object, the first line object contains. I'm sorry if I'm not clear or if I'm wrong.

Comment: Keep the arraylist and required object declared outside the if-else and use it in both places.

Comment: I dnt know what you try to do with if(line_index > 0){... section. Please explain that a bit.

Comment: I tried to separate the two types of objects and the only way I could think of was to create line_index and increment it after creating the first object. But it's obviously flawed but I don't know what else to do

Comment: Check the edited code. If I have understood your problem correctly, it shld work.

Comment: Oh mate, you're the best! Thank you so so much!